# OnClick Button not forward to URL

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP/HTML button who was link to

```
<a href="#" data-mini="true" data-role="button" onClick="window.open('../index.php', '_self');"><? echo "Login"; ?></a>
```

Now I want change to other link to url `www.button.com/index.html` I changed the ine as :

```
  <a href="#" data-mini="true" data-role="button" onClick="window.open('www.button.com/index.html', '_self');"><? echo "Login"; ?></a>
```

the second url is located on same server in other folder , but click on button not forward to link.

Comment: external url calls such as `www` require `http://` and even if it's on the same server. You can delete the question now.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify the protocol (e.g. `http`), the function assumes you want to go to a page on the same domain.
Try something like this:

```
<a href="#" data-mini="true" data-role="button" onclick="window.open('http://www.button.com/index.html', '_self');"><?="Login" ?></a>
```

Also, why are you using a JavaScript event? You could simplify this a lot by just putting the URL in the `href` attribute (`href="//www.button.com"`).

Comment: [*Yeah, I said that 15 mins. prior to this...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518442/onclick-button-not-forward-to-url#comment58727268_35518442) - Maybe they'll answer you, instead of comments.

Comment: <a href="#" data-mini="true" data-role="button" onclick="window.open('http://www.button.com/index.html', '_self');"><?="Login" ?></a> Solved the problem